# Excel: How to get a locale-independent printer name?

Tags: excel-2003, excel, printing, localization, vba

There's a `PrintOut` method in Excel that prints stuff.
It accepts a printer name as a parameter, and that printer name is not just a system printer name, but a combination of both system printer name and port to which the printer is connected.

```
.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="MyPrinter" & " on " & "Ne00:"
```

If you only provide a system name, Excel will not find it and will not print.

Note that `" on "` piece in the middle. It is actual English word "on" that makes "excel printer name" human-friendly.

The problem is, this little piece is different on each localised version of Excel. Therefore, code that wants to compose true "excel printer name" would need to include a huge `switch` where all possible Excel locales would be listed with corresponding translation of "on". I haven't even got such list. But I would like to have it, or to hear about a way to figure out this piece on the fly. The `Application.International` property does not seem to contain an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This guy uses the registry entries at

\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices\

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2008/04/05/getting-the-printer-port/

Comment: I know how to get printer's port.
This guy is doing it wrong, btw. Correct way, for compatibility reasons, is to use GetProfileString function. But my question is about different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the `ActivePrinter` property. It will return the string as per the locale. Once you have the string, you can get what exact version of "on" to use!