# Selecting printer in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing

When trying to print out on a specific printer in excel, it gives an error message when the server changes its' prompt. When trying to fix this, I used the "on error resume next" function, but that is just ugly (and does not work all the time).

This is my current formula

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne01:"
On Error Resume Next
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne02:"
On Error Resume Next
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne03:"
On Error Resume Next
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne04:"
On Error Resume Next
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne05:"
On Error Resume Next
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne06:"
On Error Resume Next
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne07:"
On Error Resume Next
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04 op Ne08:"
On Error Resume Next
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProfileString Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetProfileStringA" (ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function GetProfileString Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetProfileStringA" (ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
#End If
```

```
Public Function GetPrinterPort(ByVal PrinterName As String) As String
  Dim t As Long

  Do
    GetPrinterPort = String$(Len(GetPrinterPort) + 256, 0)
    t = GetProfileString("PrinterPorts", PrinterName, "", GetPrinterPort, Len(GetPrinterPort))
  Loop Until t < Len(GetPrinterPort) - 1

  If t <= 0 Then Err.Raise 5, , "Cannot get printer port for " & PrinterName

  GetPrinterPort = Split(Left$(GetPrinterPort, t), ",")(1)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
port = GetPrinterPort("\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi04")
```

Then use `port` to build the complete printer name. You might want to respect [localization issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2148959/11683).